# Firebase delete doc upon uploading .json

Tags: json, firebase, import, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage

In Firebase, I would like to delete docs in the collections upon comparing data in the uploaded file. How to write a function pls?

Example: file "mail_addresses_06/14/21.json" uploaded to Storage/Import. The data containing:

```
{
"EmployeesOut" : [
"john.example@mail.com",
"liz.example@mail.com",
"eve.example@mail.com"
]
}
```

Delete documents with names same as those mail addresses from the collection "UserWhiteList" in Firestore Database

Thanks a lot, JR

Comment: "uploaded to Storage/Import." => What do you exactly mean? Uploaded to Cloud Storage?

Comment: @RenaudTarnec to https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/project-name/storage/project-name.appspot.com/files~2FImport

Comment: @JakubReitinger Welcome to StackOverflow. This question is a little broad for what SO is good at. For now, take a look at the docs on creating a [Cloud Storage Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/gcp-storage-events), in particular the [`onFinalize`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/providers_storage_.objectbuilder#onfinalize) event. You'll need to familiarize yourself with the [Node.js Cloud Storage Client SDK](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/) (which is used by the Firebase Admin SDK) to read the file. (1/2)

Comment: Once you've gotten yourself stuck, then edit this question/post a new question about that **specific** problem. Then we'll be able to help out. If you are truely stuck, consider hiring a freelancer to dedicate some time to writing a well tested solution. (2/2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following Cloud Function code should do the trick:

```
exports.deleteUsers = functions.storage.object().onFinalize(async (object) => {

    const fileBucket = object.bucket; // The Storage bucket that contains the file.
    const filePath = object.name; // File path in the bucket.

    const file = admin
        .storage()
        .bucket(fileBucket)
        .file(filePath);

    const fileData = await file.download();
    const contents = JSON.parse(fileData[0].toString());
    const employeesOut = contents.EmployeesOut;

    const db = admin.firestore();
    const batch = db.batch();

    for (const property in employeesOut) {
        const docRef = db.collection("UserWhiteList").doc(employeesOut[property]);
        batch.delete(docRef);
    }

    return batch.commit();

});
```

See the corresponding doc items:

- [Trigger a Cloud Function on Cloud Storage changes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/gcp-storage-events)
- [How to download a file in memory with the Google Cloud Storage Node.js Client](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/File.html#download)
- [Batched Writes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions?authuser=0#batched-writes) for the deletions (note the limit of 500 operations)